# Problem in integrating twitter with android

Tags: android, twitter

I want to integrate twitter to my android app for that I have referred [link](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/1089/)

I have used the code for my main activity`Twitter my_twiter;

```
Button btn_login;
EditText edit_user_name;
EditText edit_password;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_loin_button);
    edit_user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_username_edit_text);
    edit_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password_edit_text);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    String userName = edit_user_name.getText().toString();
    String password = edit_password.getText().toString();
    my_twiter = new Twitter(userName,password);
    if(my_twiter == null)
    {
     Toast.makeText(TwitActivty.this, "Incorrect Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else 
    {
//          Toast.makeText(TwitActivty.this, "Worked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try
        {
         Log.i("Twitter Status :",my_twiter.getStatus()+"");
         Intent intent = new Intent(TwitActivty.this,Twitter_Info_Activity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }`
```

But I am getting the Exception

>

> 07-04 13:47:37.224: WARN/System.err(840): winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException$E401: Unauthorized
>   07-04 13:47:37.224: WARN/System.err(840): http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=6& ()
>   07-04 13:47:37.233: WARN/System.err(840):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:364)
>   07-04 13:47:37.233: WARN/System.err(840):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.connect(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:198)
>   07-04 13:47:37.233: WARN/System.err(840):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.getPage(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:239)
>   07-04 13:47:37.243: WARN/System.err(840):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.getStatus(Twitter.java:2244)
>   07-04 13:47:37.243: WARN/System.err(840):     at com.twit.TwitActivty.onClick(TwitActivty.java:51)
>   07-04 13:47:37.243: WARN/System.err(840):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   07-04 13:47:37.253: WARN/System.err(840):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>   07-04 13:47:37.253: WARN/System.err(840):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   07-04 13:47:37.263: WARN/System.err(840):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   07-04 13:47:37.263: WARN/System.err(840):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   07-04 13:47:37.263: WARN/System.err(840):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   07-04 13:47:37.273: WARN/System.err(840):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-04 13:47:37.273: WARN/System.err(840):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   07-04 13:47:37.293: WARN/System.err(840):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   07-04 13:47:37.303: WARN/System.err(840):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   07-04 13:47:37.303: WARN/System.err(840):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I am not getting where I am wrong OR tell me better alternative way to integrate with twitter please Help Me